# App Crashed when moves to onlocationchanged method from onMapready method

Tags: android, google-maps

I am Learning maps in android to show a location of user in map.Firstly, I was using .getmap() function to get the map initialize but it was depreciated, then after searching from google I came upto onMapready() I made slightly amendments and used onMapready().

But my map variable works only in default location, it doesn't run the onlocationchange method.The mMap variable have null value after returning from onMapreadyfunction and only show sydney(default) location on map.I have used a condition in OnCreate to check mMap and always gives null and doesn't go to else condition in .How my onlocationmethod can work?

I have google a lot some have used GoogleApi client but I haven't any idea about it.Moreover, I am not sure that the approach I have used is valid to get location of user.Is my there any more work to do in onMapreadyFuction?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

    if (mMap==null)  // check mMap null after onMapready
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"My Toast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling

        return;
    }

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location!=null)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"My Toast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
 }

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No sydney?",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0,0)).title("Your location"));

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Double lat = location.getLatitude();
    Double lng = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng pos = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"My Toast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title("Your location"));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 12)) ;

}
```

Comment: post your logcat of crash.

Comment: why are you initialising your map again in `onLocationChanged()` method??. You have already called `getMapAsync()` in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: @SripadRaj It was crashing because mMap doen't initialzed with google maps.that's why I have placed a check  in Oncreate to check if it is null the show toast otherwise run else condtion but it always show toast.

Comment: @VivekMishra well I have removed it now but the problem is that its not calling the onlocation method (else condition) after being initialized from onMapready().mMap is null due to which toast appears.

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with two different requirements, showing a Google Map fragment & monitoring location updates, hence you should treat them separately.

**Google Map** is initialized once you call `getMapAsync`, asynchronously (as the name implies) so it does not interrupt any other work. It's very important to have only one instance of googleMap (i.e. calling the aforementioned method only once), otherwise you will face unexpected behavior.

You should call `getMapAsync` in `onCreate` and do whatever you want with the map instance in `onMapReady`, which is guaranteed to be called once the `GoogleMap` instance is available. Remove any other call to `getMapAsync`.

**Location Updates** are requested  from the `LocationManager` like you did. This provider works asynchronously as well, so its callback, `onLocatedUpdated`, may be called before the map is ready. In this callback and in any other method that uses the map instance but may be called before the instance is available, you **must check if the map instance isn't null** before working with it, otherwise you will face a `NullPointerException`.